# get uploaded file path from API Controller to Angular controller

Tags: javascript, .net, angular

I'm trying to get uploaded file path in wwwroot in api project(.net core) in my angular controller as a response.

Comment: Is this a .Net problem or an Angular problem?  Do you have an ASP MVC application that renders a view that uses Angular?

Comment: I am getting the path in .net.         await response.SendFileAsync(documentContent);  but its not reaching in the angular js controller as response.

Comment: Is this AngularJS or Angular?  Why aren't you using the Angular routing mechanisms?

Comment: its AngularJS. actually, our intention is to make a template dynamic. for each person, we will change the name in the document (this is happening in C#) and replace the file that's working fine. but I was not able to get that in angular js. I want to show that in the iframe

Comment: My suggestion would be to review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question.  This will help you obtain a better answer.

Comment: Can you share the code in angular and the api code. It is difficult to answer without example.